# Dictionary comprehension whilst checking if key already exists?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I know you can check if a key exists using:

```
if key in mydict:
    ...
```

but I wish to somehow use this in a dictionary comprehension as I construct the dictionary.

For example:

```
mylist = [('a', 0.01), ('b', 0.02), ('c', 0.03), ('a', 0.04)]
mydict = {item[0]: item[1] for item in mylist if item[0] not in mydict else blah blah}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

I need the else part also.

Edit: For clarification. In my case I actually need the sum of item[1] values for all items with a given item[0] value.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have edited the question as I forgot to mention the else part is important for my task

Comment: `not in mydict` - you can not refer a dict before it was finally created. In Python, assignment goes from "right" to "left"

Comment: What logic is behind that `blah blah`? Dict has [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) methods which support default values. Depending on what exactly you want to do, you could probably use those methods.

Answer (score 4):

**With** dictionary comprehension:

```
mylist = [('a', 0.01), ('b', 0.02), ('c', 0.03), ('a', 0.04)]
mydict = {key:value for key, value in mylist[::-1]}
print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0.01, 'c': 0.03, 'b': 0.02}
```

**Without** dictionary comprehension:

```
mydict = {}
for key, value in mylist:
    if key not in mydict:
        mydict[key] = value
    else:
        # You asked for the else part. Do whatever here.   
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0.01, 'c': 0.03, 'b': 0.02}
```

Comment: Yes, `mydict[key] = value` seems to be a better performer in terms of speed. But I valued readability.

Comment: Trust me when I say that a Python programmer expects to see `mydict[key] = value`. It's the most readable option. `update()` is for *merging* dictionaries with defined rules about overwrites of existing keys. When I see `update()` I immediately think possible key collisions and multiple values being overwritten.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Updated my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a O(n2)?

Answer (score 2):

Python dict is unordered structure with unique keys.
As you need values of firstly encountered keys - iterate input list in reversed order:

```
mylist = [('a', 0.01), ('b', 0.02), ('c', 0.03), ('a', 0.04)]
mydict = {t[0]:t[1] for t in mylist[::-1]}

print(mydict)
```

The output:

```
{'a': 0.01, 'c': 0.03, 'b': 0.02}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I edited the question as I initially forgot to mention I require else logic. Perhaps I can't use dict comprehension in a single line.

Comment: @JSStuball: For clarification, when you say you need the else logic do you need it to produce a different key?   Do you need to combine values in some way? Do you just need to filter out duplicates? Could you expand on that a little?